# Can I use Names to reference the fields I want?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me elaborate here more. I'm not very GOOD with SQL. In the following Query, I am pulling code names. Each code name is unique. For example, '87507' references to 'Electronics'. When running a query, is it possible to replace the actual number with the name in the table?

```
Select Distinct CLM_CC9
From Impact.dbo.tbl_cld
Where CLM_CC9 in ('8203','34004','86754','87507',
'8759','8523','8526','8552','8761','8562','8778','8587','7588',
'8759','8790','8594','8796','8701','8607','8713','8616','8617',
'8718','8619','87620','8621','8764','7628','8629','7631','8632',
'833','8734','8635','8736','7637','8738','8639','7640','8641','896    08') 
order by CLM_CC9
```

Tried this..no luck...

```
Select distinct CLM_CC9,
case when CLM_CC9 = '87507' then Electronics 
when CLM_CC9 = '86754' then Toys
end as names
From Impact.dbo.tbl_cld
Where CLM_CC9 in ('8203','34004','86754','87507',
'8759','8523','8526','8552','8761','8562','8778','8587','7588',
'8759','8790','8594','8796','8701','8607','8713','8616','8617',
'8718','8619','87620','8621','8764','7628','8629','7631','8632',
'833','8734','8635','8736','7637','8738','8639','7640','8641','896    08') 
 order by CLM_CC9
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the name field to the SELECT?   `SELECT DISTINCT CLM_CC9, <name_field>`?

Comment: I have not. What is the syntax for that? Place <name_field> after the quotation marks?

Comment: Umm, no, you need to find the name of the field in your table that holds the name and then put it where I did in my example...

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct CLM_CC9,
       case when CLM_CC9 = '87507' then Electronics 
            when CLM_CC9 = '86754' then something
            ... -- add more statements as needed.
       end as somename
From Impact.dbo.tbl_cld
Where CLM_CC9 in ('8203','34004','86754','87507',
'8759','8523','8526','8552','8761','8562','8778','8587','7588',
'8759','8790','8594','8796','8701','8607','8713','8616','8617',
'8718','8619','87620','8621','8764','7628','8629','7631','8632',
'833','8734','8635','8736','7637','8738','8639','7640','8641','896    08') 
 order by CLM_CC9
```

You can use `case` statements. Or construct a lookup table if you would query repeatedly for this.

If you have the column in the table, you can just do,

```
Select distinct namecolumn
From Impact.dbo.tbl_cld
Where CLM_CC9 in ('8203','34004','86754','87507',
'8759','8523','8526','8552','8761','8562','8778','8587','7588',
'8759','8790','8594','8796','8701','8607','8713','8616','8617',
'8718','8619','87620','8621','8764','7628','8629','7631','8632',
'833','8734','8635','8736','7637','8738','8639','7640','8641','896    08') 
order by CLM_CC9
```

Also make sure you eliminate duplicate values in the `in` clause.

Comment: `with the name in the table` implies the value is in the table.

Comment: When I perform the case statement, SQL Server does not recognize that usage?

Comment: what does that mean? if you have the name column in your table, you should use the second query.

Comment: SQL server is not recognizing the use of 'case'.

Comment: also recommend using a lookup table for this.  you can add a column 'isImpactTarget' Y/N to mark your clm_cc9 values instead of listing them in your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you want something like this:

```
SELECT
CASE CLM_CC9
    WHEN '87507' THEN 'Electronics'
    [WHEN when_value THEN statements]
    ELSE statements
END
```

Comment: `with the name in the table` implies the value is in the table.